# Cannot install mongodb module for nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I am currently using node version 0.10.28

When i am issuing *node-gyp install* it is hanging and i can not do anything.

I want to install mongodb driver for node.js.(*npm install mongodb*). But when i tried this it says first build the node-gyp and try again.

I am stuck!!

Here is the commands.

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin>npm install mongodb
npm WARN package.json github-url-from-git@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bson
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder

> kerberos@0.0.3 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\m
ongodb\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerbe
ros>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_
modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
```

After this screen it halts.

Comment: The least you can do is to provide some logs, tell us which versions of `node` and `npm` you have, which platform is this, etc. Without that, we're as stuck as you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions in (https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongodb) this documentation to install and use mongo db with node , make sure you are using an 64 bit os version which will help you better to work with mongo db.
Also try installing using npm with registry setting on command.